# how to find active threads in glassfish server?

Tags: java, web, load, glassfish, webserver

I am trying to make a load balancer for my application. This load balancer will redirect the request from one server to another server. First the primary server checks the thread count of its own and thread count of the secondry server. Then it decides which server is going to handle the request according to the thread count of both the servers.

Please help me to find how to find the load of the glassfish server.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)